# Merge object and add keys from JSON format using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a list of array that is queried that needs to be merged with the same location_id  based on the objects.

**this are the code for generating array **

```
       filled  =  Product.on_hand_location(pid).to_a
       empty   =  Product.on_hand_location_empty_cylinder(pid).to_a
       data    = filled + empty 
  
 
       result = data.map{ |k| 
        { 
        details: { 
              location_id: k['location_id'],
              "location_name"=>k['location_name'],
              "onhandcylynder"=>k['onhand'] == nil ?  0 :  k['onhand'],
              "emptycylynder"=> k['emptyonhand'] == nil ?  0 :  k['emptyonhand']
           } ,
        }
     }
    
    respond_with [ onhand: result ]
```

This JSON format below is the  output of code above. which has location_id that needs to be merge

```
[{
    "onhand": [{
            "details": {
                "location_id": 1,
                "location_name": "Capitol Drive",
                "onhandcylynder": "4.0",
                "emptycylynder": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "details": {
                "location_id": 2,
                "location_name": "SM City Butuan",
                "onhandcylynder": "5.0",
                "emptycylynder": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "details": {
                "location_id": 1,
                "location_name": null,
                "onhandcylynder": 0,
                "emptycylynder": "2.0"
            }
        }
    ]
  }]
```

**My desired output**

```
  [{
     "onhand": [{
        "details": {
            "location_id": 1,
            "location_name": "Capitol Drive",
            "onhandcylynder": "4.0",
            "emptycylynder": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "details": {
            "location_id": 2,
            "location_name": "SM City Butuan",
            "onhandcylynder": "5.0",
            "emptycylynder": "2.0"
        }
    }
   ]
 }]
```

Comment: to clarify your question: there can only be 2 instances of the same object right? 1 from `filled` and 1 from `empty`. and `filled` is always the source of truth?

Comment: @ussu yes correct I only concat  this 2 array from instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactor my code and able to get my desired result

```
  filled  =  Product.on_hand_location(pid).to_a
  emptyTank =  Product.on_hand_location_empty_cylinder(pid).to_a
  data = filled + emptyTank 
  
  cylinder = data.map(&:dup)
  .group_by { |e| e.delete('location_id') }

   finalResult = cylinder.map{|_, location_id | location_id.reduce({}) { |result, location_id|
     result.merge(location_id)
  } }

  respond_with [ onhand: finalResult]
```

The result already merge with the same location id and emptyonhand keys are merge already in corresponding to its location ID

```
[
{
    "onhand": [
        {
            "onhand": "1.0",
            "location_name": "Capitol Drive",
            "emptyonhand": "5.0"
        },
        {
            "onhand": "5.0",
            "location_name": "SM City Butuan"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `data = filled + empty` you should try

```rb
data = Product.on_hand_location(pid).to_a
empty = Product.on_hand_location_empty_cylinder(pid).to_a
empty.each do |location|
  data.push(location) if data.none? { |item| item['location_id'] == product['location_id'] }
end 
 
result = ...
```

or

```rb
hash = {}
Product.on_hand_location_empty_cylinder(pid).map { |l| hash[l['location_id']] = l }
Product.on_hand_location(pid).map { |l| hash[l['location_id']] = l }
data = hash.values
```

and if you need some data from both of the queries you should try

```rb
hash = {}
Product.on_hand_location_empty_cylinder(pid).map { |l| hash[l['location_id']] = l }
Product.on_hand_location(pid).map { |l| hash[l['location_id']].merge!(l) }
data = hash.values
```

to merge in place

Comment: The result only show without emptyonhand keys    [
 {
  "onhand": [
   {
    "location_id": 1,
    "onhand": "4.0",
    "location_name": "Capitol Drive",
    "uom": 6,
    "ratio": "1.0",
    "uom_name": "pcs"
   },
   {
    "location_id": 2,
    "onhand": "5.0",
    "location_name": "SM City Butuan",
    "uom": 6,
    "ratio": "1.0",
    "uom_name": "pcs"
   }
  ]
 }
]

Comment: did you do the `map()` step where you convert the key names etc? i don't understand where the `uom` and `uom_name` come from they aren't in the jsons from your initial question
and `emptyonhand` comes from the `on_hand_location_empty_cylinder` right? if yes i added the relevant commands at the end of my answer